# Small set of acts over a countable monoid?

Tags: set-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Given a countable monoid $S$, is the set of all (isomorphic representatives of) $S$-acts a small set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $S$-act means a set with an $S$-action that can't be decomposed into two nonempty subsets both invariant under $S$.  Then the answer to the question is no.  Let $S$ be the 2-element monoid that isn't a group, i.e., the multiplicative monoid $\{0,1\}$, and let $\kappa$ be any non-zero cardinal number.  Then there is an $S$-act of cardinality $\kappa$ in which 0 acts as a constant map.  For different cardinals $\kappa$, you get non-isomorphic $S$-acts.